# I get an error about wrong dictionary update sequence length when trying to read lines from txt file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through multiple lines and add that into a dictionary, then a dataframe.

I've had many attempts but no solution yet.

I have a txt file with multiple lines like this for example, and I'm trying to iterate through each line, add it to a dictionary and then append the dictionary to a dataframe.

So textfile for example would go from here:

```
ABC=123, DEF="456", 
ABC="789", DEF="101112"
```

I would like this be added to a dictionary like this (on the first loop, for the first line):

```
{ABC:123,DEF=456}
```

and then appended to a df like this

```
   ABC   DEF
 0 123   456
 1 789   101112
```

So far I have tried this, this only works for one line in the text file, when I add a new line, I get this error:

> dictionary update sequence element #6 has length 3; 2 is required

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    s = f.read().strip()
    dictionary = dict(subString.split("=") for subString in s.split(","))
    dataframe = dataframe.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
dataframe
```

Comment: Remember that `s` reads the entire file.  You would need to split by lines first, then by commas.  Or, use `readlines()` and iterate through the lines.

Comment: @TimRoberts or just iterate through the file with a `for` loop, it will give it to you line by line.

Comment: This is a problem with your data.  I would guess that you forgot the comma at the end of one of your lines - but guessing is all I can do, in the absence of the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is to parse each line with regex, and then insert the matches (if found) into the dictionary.  You can change the regex pattern as needed, but this one matches words on the left side of `=` with numbers on the right which start with `'` or `"`.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = r'(\w+)=[\'\"]?(\d+)'

str_dict = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    for key, val in re.findall(pattern, line):
        str_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(int(val))

df = pd.DataFrame(str_dict)
```

This is how I chose the [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Nwo1hB/1)

Comment: thank you so much, this worked for the specific string in my example!

Answer (score 0):

This also works in the scenario of a huge text file with many different strings:

```
import re


file = open('event.txt', 'r').readlines()
for group in file:
    output1 = group.replace('Event time', 'Event_time')
    words = re.findall(r'".*?"', str(output1))
    for word in words:
        text = str(output1).replace(word, word.replace(" ", "_"))
    output2 = text.strip().split(' ')
    for section in output2:
        key,val = section.strip().split('=')
        data_dict[key.strip()] = val.strip()
    df = df.append(data_dict, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```